# Subset rows which are not duplicates

Tags: r

I have a data set (data.frame) composed mainly by duplicated rows. I´d like to subset it in order to get only the rows which didn´t have duplicates originally. Example of original df:

```
df1 <- data.frame( ID = c("1", "1","2","2","3","3","4","4"), V_1 = c(2011,2011,NA,NA,1,10,7,7), V_2= c(5,5,6,6,15,15,8,2))
```

Answer I´d like to get:

```
df2 <- data.frame( ID = c("3","3","4","4"), V_1 = c(1,10,7,7), V_2= c(15,15,8,2))
```

Using `unique(df1)` function gives me the complete list of unique rows (in the case of the example, 6). Since my df has more than 200k rows, it is not adequate for me.

I have searched for similar questions:
[Subset with unique cases, based on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369961/subset-with-unique-cases-based-on-multiple-columns), [Filter rows based on multiple column conditions R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18589595/filter-rows-based-on-multiple-column-conditions-r), but none of them helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go

```
duplicated.i = duplicated(df1) | (duplicated(df1[nrow(df1):1,]))[nrow(df1):1]
df2 = df1[!duplicated.i,]

# ID V_1 V_2
# 5  3   1  15
# 6  3  10  15
# 7  4   7   8
# 8  4   7   2
```

Answer (score 1):

We can remove the ID's of the duplicated rows and exclude them from the entire data frame

```
df1[!df1$ID %in% df1[duplicated(df1),1 ], ]

#  ID V_1 V_2
#5  3   1  15
#6  3  10  15
#7  4   7   8
#8  4   7   2
```